# как создать инсталлятор nw.js приложения для linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, веб-программирование

Я разработал программу на nw.js. Сделал сборки через Web2Executable для windows, linux. Для windows сделал инсталлятор, как сделать аналогичный для linux? В наличии виртуальная машина с ubuntu